# Java Socket Programming: How to send <STX>string-data<ETX> over TCP connection to the server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient, serversocket, tcplistener

I have to establish a TCP connection to a server, which requires that I send the credential to logon in the format:

**< STX >username=fred&password=123456< ETX >**

Let's say host: qstage.thetcphost.com and port:8999

I am new to socket programming and using the same to implement this. I have used java.net.Socket at the client side but I dont know how do I send the above string for authentication to the TCP Server in Java.

I am able to connect to the server but how do I pass the credential string in the < STX >...< ETX > format after (or during): 
Socket socket = new Socket("mshxml.morningstar.com", 8999);

I mean what is the piece of code that I have to write (after above line) to send this data (username & password wrapped in STX and ETX) in order to authenticate myself to the TCP server?

I have searched this site for this info but could not find any. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code goes like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("msd4xml.abcd.com", 8999, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8999);
    System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
    InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
    int stx = 0x02;
    int etx = 0x03;

    dout.writeByte(stx);
    dout.writeBytes("username=fred&password=12345");   // this line gives error, infact every 2nd writeByte(s) gives error.
    dout.writeByte(etx);
```

It's giving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
at com.voya.socketprog.Client.main(Client.java:44)
```

Comment: With a `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Yes I am using DataOutputStream but how to send the data with <STX> and <ETX> tags. Is it like this: 
int stx = 2, etx = 3;
String STX = new Character((char)stx).toString();
String ETX = new Character((char)etx).toString();
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(STX+"username=fred&password=123456"+ETX);

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`writeByte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeByte(int)) to send STX, ETX.

```
static final int STX = 2;
static final int ETX = 3;

dataOutputStream.writeByte(STX);
dataOutputStream.writeBytes("username=fred&password=123456");
dataOutputStream.writeByte(ETX);
```

Comment: thanks :)  I will update you as soon as I get to verify it. Btw, shouldn't ETX = 3 instead of 2?

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying @weston. I tried but it didnt work. I tried using: char stx = '\u0002' and String stx = "\u0002" but it didnt work too. Any more alternatives?

Comment: Just saying it didn't work doesn't give me anywhere to go. What happened exactly? did anything get sent?

Comment: @Pratap The reset problem has already been answered in one of your numerous duplicates. You shouldn't be posting duplicates anyway but especially if you're never going to read the answers you get.

Comment: @EJP the problem has not been resolved even after updating the code with your valuable suggestions on these duplicates. Btw sorry for the duplicates but I am still unable to get my issue resolved.

Comment: I have added the code and error it gives during debugging. What could be the issue? @weston NOTE: I am able to replicate this through a TCP utility called Hercules but not able to do it programatically

Comment: @Pratap This question is closed. Further discussion should take place in the duplicated question.